# 502 Bad Gateway on Nginx acting as Reverse proxy to add ssl for Upsource and Hub

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have set up Jetbrains Hub and Upsource on a machine using the ports 1111 and 1112 respectively.

These work, and if I access the machines using the local-network ip address of the machine they load.

I have then added (as per official docs) a reverse proxy for each of them to add an ssl layer on top of them using the given configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/pub.crt
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/pub.key

    server_name  mydomainForThisMachine.com;

    location  / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # to proxy WebSockets in nginx
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111/;
    }
}


server {
    listen 8081 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/pub.crt
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/pub.key

    server_name  mydomainForThisMachine.com;

    location  / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # to proxy WebSockets in nginx
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1112/;
    }
}
```

This should, as i understand, forward port 8080 to port 1111 for Hub and 8081 to 1112 for Upsource

I have opened the ports using firewall-cmd and semanage.

However, when i try to access the https://mydomainForThisMachine.com:8080/ or :8081,  The page loads using the certificates however I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. How can I even begin to solve this, is there something wrong with my configuration?

**UPDATE**
After adding error logs to nginx i find this error when I try to connect:

2016/07/07 22:37:08 [crit] 26241#0: 
*1754 connect() to 127.0.0.1:1111 failed (13: Permission denied) 
while connecting to upstream, 
client: myPublicIp, 
server: mydomainForThisMachine.com, 
request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1111/favicon.ico", 
host: "mydomainForThisMachine.com:8080", 
referrer: "https://mydomainForThisMachine.com:8080/"

Answer (score -1):

I gave up on solving it effectively and disabled selinux. This worked.